# IOS 8.4 UIActivityViewController Viber crush

Tags: ios, uialertview, viber

I use UIActivityViewController for posting text and image to socials. When I tap Viber, it give me console messages:

**1)plugin com.viber.app-share-extension interrupted**

**2)Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)" (connection to service named com.viber.app-share-extension) UserInfo=0x14f51ef0**

Code:

```
NSArray *shareItems = @[ image, message];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingArray
                                                                            applicationActivities:nil;
[self presentViewController:ac animated:YES completion:nil];'
```

How to fix it? Or how to catch exception from UIActivityViewController?